# Why is HF much more covalent than KI despite having a greater electronegativity difference?

Tags: bond, electronegativity, polarity

Generally, the percent of ionic character in a two-element compound correlates quite well with the difference in the electronegativities of the two elements making up the compound, as can be seen in this graph:

[image: Ionic v. Covalent in the Electronegativity Court]

(Image originally by the University of Florida, via user4076 [here at ChemSE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/9223/63715).)

Even here, though, an anomaly is visible.

- HF has an electronegativity difference of 1.893 (4.193 - 2.300).
- LiBr has an electronegativity difference of 1.773 (2.685 - 0.912).
- KI has an electronegativity difference of 1.625 (2.359 - 0.734).
- LiI has an electronegativity difference of 1.447 (2.359 - 0.912).

Based on this, HF should be mostly ionic - certainly more so than LiBr, KI, or *especially* LiI.  Instead, judging from the graph, HF is slightly more *covalent* than ionic, with ~45% ionic character, whereas LiBr is ~60% ionic, KI is ~75% ionic, and even LiI is ~52-53% ionic despite having a considerably-lower electronegativity difference than the ~45%-ionic HF.

Going along the sequence KI - LiBr - HF, the ionic character of the compound actually *declines steeply* as the electronegativity difference gets somewhat greater.

What is going on here?

Comment: Hints: Look up hydrogen fluoride and behold its extravagant chemical behavior. Also note hydrogen bonding is involved. Very involved!

Comment: This calculation of values is funny - precision to one thousandth, really? You're treating stupid electronegativity way too seriously, and you're only proving that you shouldn't.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound

Comment: Do you consider H+ would be just a proton/deuteron  with the extremely strong electrostatic field ?

Comment: @Poutnik Well, in the optics of OP an ionic bond to something would fix that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is KF the most ionic compound?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound)

Comment: @Alchimista: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Mithoron: All the electronegativities in question are available with that degree of precision, so why not?

Comment: @EdV: That still doesn't explain KI v. LiBr.

Comment: In my judgement, no need: the table is pretty much a waste. Chemistry has lots of trends, patterns and exceptions. Electronegativity is only one factor that, unfortunately, gets over-emphasized in early chemistry courses. And there are several ways to define electronegativity, leading to arguments such as “Is nitrogen more electronegative than chlorine or vice versa?”

Comment: @EdV: Except that difference-in-electronegativity _is directly linked to_ bond polarity and ionic character.

Comment: So why is the plot not a straight line if the difference in EN is the sole factor? I will stay with what I said.

Comment: "difference-in-electronegativity is directly linked to bond polarity and ionic character" in which electronegativity? Allen electronegativity you used has no direct connection to bonds at all.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean that is a bit surprising. In my opinion it should. If you stick to the fact that bigger the delta El Neg more polar the bond is, you won't obviously get out of this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajans%27_rules