# How would the regions of this graph showing percentage of ionic character, be classified?

Tags: ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds, electronegativity

Looking here at this website - Omnicalculator, at the section of the website for calculating percentage of ionic character. [**Omnicalculator - Percentage Ionic Character**](https://www.omnicalculator.com/chemistry/percent-ionic-character)

They let you choose elements and it calculates percentage of ionic character.

And besides showing the electronegativity difference, and the percentage of ionic character

They show criteria for determining whether something is considered non polar covalent, or polar covalent or ionic

[image]

(No doubt the first row of that table  they mean non polar covalent)

And they show this graph

[image]

I think that table leaves some gaps e.g. what if the electronegativity is < 2, but the percentage ionic character is > 63.21%  (Then it's not in any of the three rows).

And they show this graph

Looking at that graph, the second intersection is just above 60. probably 63.21% (the figure they have in their table)

There are some regions of the graph i'm not sure about..'cos their table doesn't cover it.

Any idea how they'd be categorising/classifying sections i've labelled D/E/F?

[image]

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks.. So regarding the first two columns in the table.  Or regarding the graph.  Is it saying that there's no cases where ΔEN is < 2 and IC < 63.21% ?And if it's not saying that, then how would you classify a compound that has  ΔEN is < 2 and IC < 63.21% ?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/why-are-bonds-ionic-when-the-electronegativity-difference-between-bonded-atoms-i https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation of the calculated ionic character and the Pauling electronegativity difference is the function of the ionic character model. There are no regions A-F in this context. There is just the blue curve.

For the measured ionic character, e.g. from the bond length and the bond dipole moment, the graph plays no role and there are just 3 regions nonpolar/polar/ionic according to experimental ionic character value.

Note that the threshold values are not sharply defined, they are rather fuzzy. But there is no reason not to follow the arbitrary values for the calculated values.

Note that the experimental values of ionic character and the difference of Pauling electronegativities are correlated, but not very strongly.

Comment: Thanks. And so besides 0.5<Δχ<2.0⟹6.06%<IC<63.21%,  Also,     6.06%<IC<63.21%  ⟹ 0.5<Δχ<2.0  (so that implication goes both ways). And so there are no holes in the table?

Comment: Do you see there any holes?

Comment: Not yet but I will check more combinations of elements.

Comment: They aren't truly dependent, rather correlated (not all that well).

Comment: I see what you mean re the mapping., I see there's a direct mapping between electronegativity difference and IC.  . So the folk that put the IC boundary for ionic at ~63%, use electronegativity difference of 2..  And the folk that put IC boundary for ionic at > 50%, use electronegativity difference at 1.7 or 1.8. https://www.calculatoratoz.com/en/percent-ionic-character-calculator/Calc-900

Comment: @Mithoron I do agree, it is measured versus calculated ionic character. I was speaking in context of the former. For the latter, the bond categorization does not obviously refer to electronegativity. for OP, see also https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/08%3A_Basic_Concepts_of_Chemical_Bonding/8.04%3A_Bond_Polarity_and_Electronegativity

Comment: Hehe, I have turned it upside down in the last.by error. I have obviously talked about ionic character calculated from P. electronegativity, where those regions play no role. For measured ionic character, e.g. from bond length and dipole moment, the graph plays no role and there are 3 regions nonpolar/polar/ionic according to experimental ionic character value.